# Updating local and parent state causes unmounted component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

[I have a table with buttons](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sun-wflot?file=/src/ButtonCell.js:69-854).  I want to track the number of times each individual button is clicked along with the total number of times any button has been clicked.  I can only get one-or-the-other to work.

I attempt to accomplish this by having a "global" state hook that is passed into each row of the table used for tracking total clicks.  I also have a "local" state hook that is part of each component that makes up a row in the table for tracking individual clicks.  I pass the "global" state from the parent to the children rows as a pair of callbacks (one for the getter, one for the setter).

**Error Message:**

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in ButtonCell (created by clickableButtonCell)
    in clickableButtonCell (created by Table)
```

**Problematic Code:**

```js
export default function ButtonCell({
  totalButtonClicks,
  setTotalButtonClicks
}) {
  // Having this local state variable causes the unmounted component error.
  // Removing this state and its references will cause the error to go away.
  // Or, removing the state variable passed into this component will cause
  // the error to go away and the individualClicks state will work as intended.
  const [individualClicks, setIndividualClicks] = useState(0);

  const onClick = async () => {
    await axios.get("www.github.com").then(() => {
      setTotalButtonClicks(totalButtonClicks + 1);
      setIndividualClicks(individualClicks + 1);
      return null;
    });
  };

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      Click Me! {individualClicks}
    </button>
  );
}
```

**Code Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sun-wflot?file=/src/ButtonCell.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-wing-7cwio?file=/src/ButtonCell.js
useMemo in the MyTable.js was causing rerender because of the props change (caused by setting state).

Comment: Removing async/await does not fix the problem.  If you edit my Code Sandbox example, does it resolve the problem for you?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-wing-7cwio?file=/src/ButtonCell.js

Yeah, I didn't look upper for the parent component. There was an issue with your useMemo which was getting state update (totalButtonClicks) as a prop and then it was causing rerender.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty close to what I need, but it made me realize something else.  I have a new example where I want to display individual and total clicks on each row.  In this Code Sandbox example, why do the individual button clicks no longer work and the error gets thrown in the console? https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-architecture-9cl59?file=/src/ButtonCell.js

Comment: It's 'not-working' because your Button components are being rerendered on each totalButtonClicks update. I suggest making use of React Context/Recoil. By using context, you can consume value, or update it directly without props drilling you have now.

Comment: I ended up getting it working using Context last night like you suggested!  It was a new React concept for me, but is super useful.  Thanks.